# What does this line of code mean? .agg({'account':'count'}) | Aggregation & Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I am currently learning Python through the DataCamp Data Scientist Course and I came across a line of code that doesn't make sense to me.

> In this lesson, you will explore this further by finding out what is
> the most common business owner title. (i.e., secretary, CEO, or vice
> president)

---

*Below contains the datasets that you will need:*

licenses dataset:

```
     account ward  aid                   business                     address    zip
0     307071    3  743       REGGIE'S BAR & GRILL             2105 S STATE ST  60616
1         10   10  829                 HONEYBEERS         13200 S HOUSTON AVE  60633
2      10002   14  775                CELINA DELI           5089 S ARCHER AVE  60632
3      10005   12  NaN  KRAFT FOODS NORTH AMERICA              2005 W 43RD ST  60609
4      10044   44  638  NEYBOUR'S TAVERN & GRILLE        3651 N SOUTHPORT AVE  60613
```

---

biz_owners dataset:

```
      account first_name  last_name           title
0          10      PEARL    SHERMAN       PRESIDENT
1          10      PEARL    SHERMAN       SECRETARY
2       10002     WALTER     MROZEK         PARTNER
3       10002     CELINA     BYRDAK         PARTNER
4       10005      IRENE  ROSENFELD       PRESIDENT
```

---

***Start of the assignment***

```
# Merge the licenses and biz_owners table on account
licenses_owners = licenses.merge(biz_owners, on='account')
```

****LINE OF CODE THAT I DON'T UNDERSTAND:****

```
# Group the results by title then count the number of accounts
counted_df = licenses_owners.groupby('title').agg({'account':'count'})
```

What does the `.agg({'account':'count'})` part actually mean?

In other words, how does this format give you this output?

---

**WHAT I DO UNDERSTAND:**

I understand the `.groupby()` operation and that `.agg()` is used as an operator over multiple values, but I have never seen aggregation formatted like this before.

---

**Output**

counted_df:

```
                    account
title                      
ASST. SECRETARY         111
BENEFICIARY               4
CEO                     110
DIRECTOR                146
EXECUTIVE DIRECTOR       10
GENERAL PARTNER          21
INDIVIDUAL              268
LIMITED PARTNER          26
MANAGER                 134
MANAGING MEMBER         878
```

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend you start by reading the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#:~:text=dict%20of%20axis%20labels%20%2D%3E%20functions%2C%20function%20names%20or%20list%20of%20such.) and  this [official guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), `.agg()` can accept a dictionary as follows:

> Parameters funcfunction, str, list or dict Function to use for
> aggregating the data. If a function, must either work when passed a
> DataFrame or when passed to DataFrame.apply.
>
> Accepted combinations are:
>
> - [...]
> - dict of axis labels -> functions, function names or list of such.

If using a dict, the key-value-pairs specify the axis labels (column names) and the function name which should by applied to the specified column.

The dict `{'account':'count'}` provided in your code snippet therefore applies the `count` function to the column `account` on the grouped dataframe (grouped by `title`). It therefore counts the occurrences of each `title`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an aggregate function. It will give you count of accounts based on title column. It's similar to

```py
licenses_owners.groupby('title')["account"].count()
```

.agg() gives control over different function on different column.

CEO 110 means there's 110 data with CEO as title